# How to create a bar chart?

Tags: spss, bar-chart

I want to create a bar chart with multiple variables on the x-axis.

I have variables on type of downloader (Legal, Illegal, Mixed), age (16-24, 25-34, 35+) and gender (Male, Female).

On the y-axis i just want a simple percentage
On the x-axis I want bars for total male, female, 16-24, 25-34, 35+, Male 16-24, Male 25-34, Male 35+, Female 16-24, Female 25-34, Female 35+. These all being clustered on the type of downloader (legal, illegal and mixed)

How do I create this in SPSS?

Comment: I'm confused by your description. Would perhaps paneling by gender work - with age on the x axis?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can put group totals and subgroup totals together on the x axis with spss. You could using matplotlib/numpy. However, you could do the subgroups with `graphs --> legacy dialogs --> bar charts --> clustered --> summaries of separate variables`. Not sure if that is what you want

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, it can be split in two types of problems:

1. Is it possible to have two or more separate bar charts of different
   variables (e.g. gender and agegroup) combined in one diagram?
2. How to create a grouped barchart with three variables (Gender X
   Agegroup X Downloadertype).

**On 1.:** I' don't think so. At least, there is no graphical way to get this done and I haven't found a way to do so by fiddling around with the GGRAPH/GPL Syntax. (any suggestions welcome)

**ON 2.:** The easiest way this can be done is via the Graphs->Chartbuilder dialog box.

- Choose "Clusterd Bar" from the Gallery tab (and drag it into the
  previev window).
- Drag the downloader variable on the "Cluster on X" field
- Drag gender or agegroup on the "X-Axis" field
- On the "Groups/Point ID" tab check either the "Rows" or "Columns" "panel
  variable" Box and drag the gender or agegroup variable in this field
- For percentages on the X-Axis click on "Element Properties" if this
  dialog box isn't already open. Change the "Statistic" from "Count" to
  "Percentage" and click on the "Set Parameters Button to define the
  denominator for the percentages.